# How to get the worksheet that a regular (non-ActiveX) control is on?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sub that I am calling by clicking a button.  I've chosen to use a regular button (aka Form Control), not an ActiveX one, because I've been seeing the text size on ActiveX controls fluctuating and regular buttons don't have this problem.  I want the sub to be able to use the worksheet that the button is on.  I was thinking of something like this:

```
   Sub showSheetName()

   Dim sht As Worksheet

   'this would work if the code was in the worksheet's module
   Set sht = Me

   msgbox sht.Name

   End Sub
```

But this sub is in a shared module, not the worksheet's module, because I want several sheets to be able to use it.  So `Me` doesn't point to the worksheet, and this approach just gives an `Invalid use of Me keyword`.

How can I get a reference to the worksheet that the button is on?

EDIT: If it wasn't clear, the reason why it's important that it's not an ActiveX control is because that means there's no `myButton_Click()` event in the worksheet that I can use to get the worksheet object and pass to a version of `showSheetName()` that takes a worksheet argument.

Comment: `Set sht = ActiveSheet`...

Comment: @DavidZemens, right, that should have been obvious.

Comment: You can simply use `ActiveSheet` here. Remember that to call the macro using any button on any sheet, you'll have to actually go (select) to that sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Set sht = ActiveSheet`...

This of course assumes that the procedure is being invoked manually (i.e., the user is actively clicking the button) rather than being invoked through a `Call` or `Application.Run` statement.

The button can only be clicked by the user when the worksheet is active view.

Answer (score -1):

There is no such thing as a regular button. Nor anymore are there ActiveX controls.

ActiveX is a marketing terminology by MS that described controls using COM. It, as a terminology, was retired years ago (the technology is still current).

Therefore it is hard to know what you are referring to.

Use names that HELP uses. List code that specifies the objects/etc that you are using.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, but a comment requesting clarification. Also, the Form Controls are commonly understood to be "regular" buttons, and ActiveX controls are still most certainly something you can insert as recently as Excel 2010 (I will have to confirm whether the same is true in 2013 -- I just upgraded to that software and not 100% up to speed with it yet).

Comment: But form buttons are activex controls?

Comment: People need to use formal terminolgy.

Comment: This is terminology that is built in to the application's interface. Even recently (December '14) there was a [widespread bug affecting -- according to Microsoft themselves both "types" of controls](http://blogs.technet.com/b/the_microsoft_excel_support_team_blog/archive/2014/12/11/forms-controls-stop-working-after-december-2014-updates-.aspx).  It is the only terminology that most people would know or understand.  How do you ordinarily differentiate the two sets of controls available in my Controls toolbox? http://i.imgur.com/LzFN3Iw.png

Comment: I don't. I regard a "regular" button as one created with CreateWindow, ie a non COM button. VB has a private COM for internal objects

Comment: You don't *what*? Make a distinction between the two types of controls?  Even though they are different and behave differently? What *do* you call them?

Comment: ![Form Control & ActiveX control tool box](http://nebula.wsimg.com/2b18cbc6ee82787b9b334c267628815d?AccessKeyId=21C1C50B7677872F602F&disposition=0&alloworigin=1) <br/>Why the arguing?

Comment: @Davesexcel that is exactly my point -- they are called such in the Toolbox, *and* of course they also behave differently and have different properties!

Comment: They are called regular buttons in the toolbox?